# Storing HTML5 canvas containing images

Tags: html, html5-canvas

How do you store a canvas that contains images using the toDataURL method?  Everything works fine for text and drawing, but I don't know how to handle images.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I have modified my question as follows:

This works when the image is pulled directly from a .png.  However, when I call the Google Charts API, toDataURL doesn't work even though the image renders correctly on the canvas. Google Charts is returning a .png.  Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function test() {
var c = document.getElementById("drawing-canvas");
var cxt = c.getContext("2d");

// This doesn't work.
//var imgsrc = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chf=bg,s,ffffff&chco=000000& 
chl=a';  

// This works
var imgsrc = 'chart.png'; 


var img = new Image();
img.src = imgsrc; 
cxt.drawImage(img,0,0);

}

function wr() {
var cc = document.getElementById("drawing-canvas");
var url = cc.toDataURL();
var newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(newImg);
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload = "test();">
<canvas id="drawing-canvas" width = "500px" height = "500px" style="background-color: 
#ffffff; border: 2px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
<input type = "button" value = "go" onclick = "wr();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use drawImage on the canvas and the source is a .png everything works fine. When I use an image obtained from the Google Charts API it renders correctly in the canvas, but I can't save it with toDataURL.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this worked when I saved the image on the server.  I am having problems with caching though.  I tried img.src = "chart.png' + '?' + Math.random(); but drawImage(img,x,y) doesn't work for some reason.  However, it does work when I construct img.src = 'chart.png?12345'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your chart didn't even render on the canvas when I tested it. You need to wait for the image to load. Your `chart.png` image probably loads instantaneously since it's cached, but the one generated by Google Charts API isn't. This is what you should do:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function()
{
    cxt.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
img.src = imgsrc;
```

Aside from that, you must be getting a `SECURITY_ERR` in your browser's console. This is because [the Canvas security model doesn't allow you to export images coming from an external URL](http://dropshado.ws/post/1172959582/4-8-10-2-security-with-canvas-elements-html5). You should use a server-side language to save the Google Charts image to your server, then load it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML *canvas* element has a method called `toDataURL`, that will return a data URL image representing the canvas. You can check the documentation API [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement).

Specifically, it says about `toDataURL`:

> **toDataURL**(*in optional `DOMString` type, in any ...args*)
>
> returns `DOMString`
>
> Returns a data: URL containing a representation of the image in the format specified by type (defaults to PNG).
>
> - If the height or width of the canvas is 0, "data:," representing the empty string, is returned.
> - If the type requested is not image/png, and the returned value starts with data:image/png, then the requested type is not supported.
> - Chrome supports the image/webp type.
> - If the requested type is image/jpeg or image/webp, then the second argument, if it is between 0.0 and 1.0, is treated as indicating image quality; if the second argument is anything else, the default value for image quality is used. Other arguments are ignored.

And provides and example on how to use it:

```
 function test() {
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var url = canvas.toDataURL();

     var newImg = document.createElement("img");
     newImg.src = url;
     document.body.appendChild(newImg);
 }
```

In this example, we use the dataURL as the source attribute of an `img` element, but you can do whatever you want you it (like storing it somewhere, or sending it to the server with an ajax call).

Note that *most of the methods* involved in drawing on canvas are methods of **drawing context** (obtained by a call to `getContext`), while this method is one of the **canvas element**.